# VBScript - Can we find out duration with seconds through code

Tags: vbscript

I have time in seconds... Like below

```
set seconds = 180 seconds
set seconds1 = 1500 Seconds
set seconds2 = 600 Seconds
```

based on above values output like below

```
duration = 00:03:00 
duration = 00:25:00
duration = 00:10:00
```

like i need through VBscript pls help me

Comment: Combine [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/formatdatetime-function) with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually build your HH:MM:SS string by dividing the total number of seconds into hours and minutes:

```
Function FormatSeconds(p_lngSeconds)

    Dim sReturn
    Dim lngTotalSeconds
    Dim iHours
    Dim iMinutes
    
    ' Copy value from parameter
    lngTotalSeconds = p_lngSeconds
    
    ' Calculate number of hours
    iHours = Int(lngTotalSeconds / (60 * 60))
    
    ' Subtract from total seconds
    lngTotalSeconds = lngTotalSeconds - (iHours * 60 * 60)
    
    ' Calculate numer of minutes
    iMinutes = Int(lngTotalSeconds / 60)
    
    ' Subtract from total seconds
    lngTotalSeconds = lngTotalSeconds - (iMinutes * 60)
    
    ' Build string
    sReturn = iHours & ":" & Right("0" & iMinutes, 2) & ":" & Right("0" & lngTotalSeconds, 2)

    FormatSeconds = sReturn

End Function
```

Going back to your question, you'd use this function thusly:

```
duration = FormatSeconds(seconds)
```

Comment: This function calling syntax is works in vbscript?

Comment: vbscript function return only boolean value like true or false only am i right?? if we return any string or in getting error like "Type mismatch"

Comment: @RajuRaj a vbscript function can return anything. However, not every operation works on any data type, so when you use the return value from a function (or any value, in fact), you must take that into account. For example, you can multiply a number, but not a string (obviously). Note that VBScript is loosely typed, meaning that you do not beforehand specify the type of a variable, nor the return type of a function..